# How to move element inside a grid more to the left

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have code as below. I want to make sure that that textArea1 will be next to textAreaLabel1 but right now it is far to the left because first object which is in posistion row = 0, column = 0 and is very long.
How can i make it be right next to each other ?

[image]

```
import tkinter as tk

class MainFrame(tk.Tk):
    """ This is main class for managing different views(windows) """
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------     
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        # init main frame
        container = tk.Frame(self, width=500, height=300)
#         container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        # stores starting options
        self.checkBoxDict = dict()

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        # add start info
        entryInfo = tk.Label(text = "Choose your settings, one window running different algorithm will be open for every check box checked")
        entryInfo.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        # add rest of controlers
        self.addControlers()
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------     
    def addControlers(self):
        """sets rest of gui"""
        info = tk.Label(text = "Choose what algorithms(crossover) you want to compare")
        info.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky="W")

        textAreaLabel1 = tk.Label(text = "How big population ? (best 100-500)")
        textAreaLabel1.grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky="w")

        textArea1 = tk.Entry()
        textArea1.grid(row = 3, column = 1,sticky="w" )

        textAreaLabel2 = tk.Label(text = "How many points ? (best 20-50)")
        textAreaLabel2.grid(row = 4, column = 0, sticky="w")

        textArea2 = tk.Entry()
        textArea2.grid(row = 4, column = 1, sticky="W")

        self.checkBoxDict["ramdom"] = tk.BooleanVar()
        checkButton1 = tk.Checkbutton( text="Pure randomness approach", variable=self.checkBoxDict["ramdom"])
        checkButton1.grid(row = 5, column = 0, sticky="W")

        self.checkBoxDict["pmx"] = tk.BooleanVar()
        checkButton2 = tk.Checkbutton( text="PMX crossover", variable=self.checkBoxDict["pmx"])
        checkButton2.grid(row = 6, column = 0, sticky="W")

        self.checkBoxDict["mutation"] = tk.BooleanVar()
        checkButton3 = tk.Checkbutton( text="Only mutation no crossover", variable=self.checkBoxDict["mutation"]   )
        checkButton3.grid(row = 7, column = 0, sticky="W")
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------     

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------     
app = MainFrame()
app.mainloop()
```

***UPDATE*** 
This started to work for me as i wished

```
...       
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)

        # add start info
        entryInfo = tk.Label(text = "Choose your settings, one window running different algorithm will be open for every check box checked")
        entryInfo.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan=10)
        # add rest of controlers
        self.addControlers()
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------     
    def addControlers(self):
        """sets rest of gui"""
        info = tk.Label(text = "Choose what algorithms(crossover) you want to compare")
        info.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky="w", columnspan=10)

        textAreaLabel1 = tk.Label(text = "How big population ? (best 100-500)")
        textAreaLabel1.grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky="w")

        textArea1 = tk.Entry()
        textArea1.grid(row = 3, column = 1,sticky="w")

        textAreaLabel2 = tk.Label(text = "How many points ? (best 20-50)")
        textAreaLabel2.grid(row = 4, column = 0, sticky="w")

        textArea2 = tk.Entry()
        textArea2.grid(row = 4, column = 1, sticky="W")

        self.checkBoxDict["ramdom"] = tk.BooleanVar()
        checkButton1 = tk.Checkbutton( text="Pure randomness approach", variable=self.checkBoxDict["ramdom"])
        checkButton1.grid(row = 5, column = 0, sticky="W")

        self.checkBoxDict["pmx"] = tk.BooleanVar()
        checkButton2 = tk.Checkbutton( text="PMX crossover", variable=self.checkBoxDict["pmx"])
        checkButton2.grid(row = 6, column = 0, sticky="W")

        self.checkBoxDict["mutation"] = tk.BooleanVar()
        checkButton3 = tk.Checkbutton( text="Only mutation no crossover", variable=self.checkBoxDict["mutation"]   )
        checkButton3.grid(row = 7, column = 0, sticky="W")

        startButton = tk.Button(text = "Start", bd = 3, bg = "#20aa20", command = lambda:self.start())
        startButton.grid(row = 8, sticky = "nswe", columnspan=10)
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to look at your UI as being made up of three columns rather than two, with the third column being for the extra space required by the long labels.

To do that, simply make those two long labels have a `columnspan` of 3, and then give a weight to the second or third column so that it expands as necessary for the long label.

This shows how to have the text span multiple columns:

```
entryInfo.grid(row = 0, column = 0, stickky="W", columnspan=3)
...
info.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky="W", columnspan=3)
```

This shows giving the third column a weight:

```
class MainFrame(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
        ...
```

Comment: It works but is still like no more then center of window, any ideas ?